# iTextSharp 7: Stamp with Transparency

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations, itext, itext7

Thankfully, with some help, I got my stamp working using the following code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

        Rectangle crop = pdfDoc.GetPage(1).GetCropBox();
        Debug.WriteLine("CropBox Rectangle Dim "+crop);


        float w = 0;
        float h = 0;

        ImageData img = ImageDataFactory.Create(imgsrc);

        float iWidth = img.GetWidth();
        float iHeight = img.GetHeight();
        if (crop.GetWidth() > crop.GetHeight())
        {
            w = crop.GetWidth();
            h = crop.GetHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            w = crop.GetHeight();
            h = crop.GetWidth();
        }


        Debug.WriteLine("Width = "+w+" and Height = "+h);


        Rectangle location = new Rectangle(crop.GetLeft(),crop.GetBottom(),iWidth/4,iHeight/4);


        PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(location).SetStampName(new PdfName("Logo"));

        PdfFormXObject xObj = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(iWidth, iHeight));
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObj, pdfDoc);
        canvas.AddImage(img, 0, 0,iWidth, false);
        stamp.SetNormalAppearance(xObj.GetPdfObject());



        stamp.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);

        pdfDoc.GetFirstPage().AddAnnotation(stamp);
        pdfDoc.Close();
```

If I am not mistaken, the process of stamping using iText involves the use of an external image file - which I did. However, unlike my Adobe stamps, the images retain their white background and hence are not transparent. In attempting to turn it into a transparent PNG, I end up with a weird result. My stamp ends up appearing with a BLACK background. My initial assumption is that the **Canvas** object has some sort of fill color that defaults to black? How would you go about setting the black fill to transparent.

I tried using the "Graphics State" (**PdfGState state**), setting its Opacity to 0, and applying it to the **Canvas**. However, that in turn sets my stamp image invisible as well. How do you go around this issue?

Comment: Stamping's just the term for adding content over or under existing content, it doesn't necessarily have to involve an external image, can be text as well. That said, have a look at the transparent background image example found in this chapter of the building blocks tutorial: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-7-handling-events-setting-viewer-preferences-and-writer-properties.
I've just skimmed the code(hence comment and not an answer), but it should provide you with a method to watermark, which sounds like the thing you're trying to do.

Comment: @Samuel Huylebroeck 
Seen Watermark examples, not entirely what I am encountering. However I looked up a different way of stamping my logos. Now I am superimposing the PDF containing the stamp. It works perfectly, but once you associate a stamp with the FormXObject ( that is the page containing the stamp), the size just messes up -- or even worse, the stamp doesn't appear. Let me know if it is worth posting the new piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after hours of staring at the screen, I found out the hard way why my stamps were dimensioned incorrectly. Apparently, the **FormXObject** that encompasses the PDF file to merge does not store the corresponding Width and Height of the page it is storing. Not only does it give a greater height when the page is clearly landscape, but it also is not reflective of the true page size. As a result, using the **FormXObject.getWidth()** and **FormXObject.getHeight()** resulted in incorrect dimensions that squashed the stamp image. Instead, use the **PdfDocument** associated with the file to merge and use the **Page().GetCropBox().GetWidth()** and **Height** accordingly.

Of course, it is needless to say that such misconception was based on my presumption of what the **FormXObject** will really do.

Here is the final code for anyone interested, note it includes some unused variables and irrelevant lines that were primarily for debugging:

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

        // Document to be edited and documented to be merged in
        PdfDocument newDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
        PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(stampsrc));

        // CropBox And Dimensions
        Rectangle crop = newDoc.GetFirstPage().GetCropBox();
        float width = crop.GetWidth();
        float height = crop.GetHeight();


        // Create FormXObject and Canvas
        PdfFormXObject page = srcDoc.GetPage(1).CopyAsFormXObject(newDoc);
        //Extract Page Dimensions
        float xWidth = srcDoc.GetFirstPage().GetCropBox().GetWidth();
        float xHeight = srcDoc.GetFirstPage().GetCropBox().GetHeight();

        Rectangle location = new Rectangle(crop.GetLeft(), crop.GetBottom(), xWidth , xHeight );



        PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(location).SetStampName(new PdfName("Logo"));
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(newDoc.GetFirstPage().NewContentStreamBefore(), newDoc.GetFirstPage().GetResources(), newDoc);

       // canvas.AddXObject(page,location.GetLeft(),location.GetBottom(),page.GetWidth());
        stamp.SetNormalAppearance(page.GetPdfObject());
        stamp.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
        newDoc.GetFirstPage().AddAnnotation(stamp);

        srcDoc.Close();
        newDoc.Close();
```

Comment: *" Apparently, the FormXObject that encompasses the PDF file to merge does not store the corresponding Width and Height of the page it is storing."* - the form XObject has the dimensions of the page **MediaBox**, not its **CropBox**.